# How to load a image from www/img/ and convert it to base64 (Angular/Ionic)?

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework, base64

I'm running an Ionic project and I need to use a social share plugin.
However, to share an image it must to be as base64. How do I load a image from www/img/ and convert it to base64 using ionic/angular?

Answer (score 0):

To download an image, set `responseType: "arraybuffer"`:

```
var config = { responseType: "arraybuffer"};

var bufferPromise = $http.get(imgUrl, config).then(function(response) {
     return response.data;
}).catch(functon (errorResponse) {
     console.log("ERROR: " + errorResponse.status);
     throw errorResponse;
});
```

Then to upload it, convert it to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and use the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
var uploadConfig = { "Content-Type": undefined };

bufferPromise.then(function (buffer) {
    var blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("part0", blob, "filename.jpg");
    return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, uploadConfig);
}).then (function (response) {
    console.log("Success");
}).catch (function (errorResponse) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + errorResponse.status);
});
```

The browser will automatically encode the blob using base64 and set `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`.

With the AngularJS framework, it is important to use a config with `"Content-Type": undefined` to prevent the framework from using `"Content-Type": application/json`